# How to use dplyr `rowwise()` column numbers instead of column names

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(col1 = c(5, 2), col2 = c(6, 4), col3 = c(9, 9))
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(col4 = sd(c(col1, col3)))
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#    col1  col2  col3  col4
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     5     6     9  2.83
# 2     2     4     9  4.95
```

After asking a series of questions I can finally calculate standard deviation across rows. See my code above.

But I can't use column names in my production code, because the database I pull from likes to change the column names periodically. Lucky for me the relative column positions is always the same.

So I'll just use column numbers instead. And let's check to make sure I can just swap things in and out:

```
identical(df$col1, df[[1]])
# [1] TRUE
```

Yes, I can just swap `df[[1]]` in place of `df$col1`. I think I do it like this.

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(col4 = sd(c(.[[1]], .[[3]])))  
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#    col1  col2  col3  col4
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     5     6     9  3.40
# 2     2     4     9  3.40

df %>% rowwise() %>% {mutate(col4 = sd(c(.[[1]], .[[3]])))} 
# Error in mutate_(.data, .dots = compat_as_lazy_dots(...)) : 
#   argument ".data" is missing, with no default
```

Nope, it looks like these don't work because the results are different from my original. And I can't use apply, if you really need to know why [I made a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55853744/why-does-base-r-ifelse-turn-my-character-vectors-into-matrices-intermittentl).

```
df %>% mutate(col4 = apply(.[, c(1, 3)], 1, sd))
```

How do I apply dplyr `rowwise()` with column numbers instead of names?

Comment: The issue with `.[[1]]` is that it is pulling the whole column.  I would use `df %>% mutate(col4 = map_dbl(row_number(), ~  sd(c(df[[1]][.x], df[[3]][.x]))))`

Comment: Shouldn't `identical(df$col1, df[[1]])` return false if that is the case?

Comment: Both are same as it is extracting the first column as a vector.  In the `rowwise`, it is row grouping, with one row per each group, but when you do `df[[1]]` or `.[[1]]`, it is breaking that structure and extract the whole rows

Comment: Along the lines of akrun's comment:
`df %>% mutate(col4 = map2_dbl(.[[1]], .[[3]], ~sd(c(.x, .y))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in using `.[[1]]` or .`[[3]]` after doing the `rowwise` (grouping by row - have only single row per group) is that it breaks the grouping structure and extracts the whole column.  Inorder to avoid that, we can create a `row_number()` column before doing the `rowwise` and then subset the columns based on that index

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% # create a sequence of row index
    rowwise %>% 
    mutate(col4 = sd(c(.[[1]][rn[1]], .[[3]][rn[1]]))) %>% #extract with index
    select(-rn)
#Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
#Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 2 x 4
#   col1  col2  col3  col4
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     5     6     9  2.83
#2     2     4     9  4.95
```

---

Or another option is `map` from `purrr` where we loop over the `row_number()` and do the subsetting of rows of dataset

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  mutate(col4 = map_dbl(row_number(), ~ sd(c(df[[1]][.x], df[[3]][.x]))))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#   col1  col2  col3  col4
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     5     6     9  2.83
#2     2     4     9  4.95
```

---

Or another option is `pmap` (if we don't want to use `row_number()`)

```
df %>%
    mutate(col4 = pmap_dbl(.[c(1, 3)], ~ sd(c(...))))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#   col1  col2  col3  col4
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     5     6     9  2.83
#2     2     4     9  4.95
```

Of course, the easiest way would be to use `rowSds` from `matrixStats` as described in the dupe tagged post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854415/can-i-apply-r-standard-deviation-across-rows-without-apply-function)

NOTE: All of the above methods doesn't require any reshaping

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't necessarily know the column names, but know the positions of the columns for which you need standard deviation, etc., I'd reshape into long data and add an ID column. You can gather by position instead of column name, either by giving the numbers of the column that should become the key, or the numbers of the columns to omit from the key. That way, you don't need to specify those values by column because you'll have them all in one column already. Then you can join those summary values back to your original wide-shaped data.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tibble(col1 = c(5, 2), col2 = c(6, 4), col3 = c(9, 9)) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number())

df %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  gather(key, value, 1, 3) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(sd = sd(value)) %>%
  inner_join(df, by = "id")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>      id    sd  col1  col2  col3
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1  2.83     5     6     9
#> 2     2  4.95     2     4     9
```

Rearrange columns by position as you need.

Answer (score 1):

An approach transposing data, converting it to matrix, computing the standard deviation, transposing again and transforming into tibble.

```
df %>%
  t %>%
  rbind(col4 = c(sd(.[c(1, 3),1]), sd(.[c(1, 3),2]))) %>%
  t %>%
  as_tibble()
```