# dplyr - inputting columns to rowwise() with column index instead of column name

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I've found an excellent solution to a problem I'm having where I want to create a new column that computes the mean of all the cells in the corresponding row here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33438918/12744116

The data is admittedly not tidy, but the solution, which I've copied below, gets the job done:

```
data %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(c=mean(c(a,b)))

#      id     a     b     c
#   (dbl) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
# 1   101     1     2   1.5
# 2   102     2     2   2.0
# 3   103     3     2   2.5
```

However, unlike this simpler example, I have far too many columns to name. I'm wondering if there's any way of quickly referring to the columns using slicing notation (i.e., instead of c(a, b), something like 2:3) or some other way of referring to the columns via their index.

I've found something similar on another Stack Overflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55855570/how-to-use-dplyr-rowwise-column-numbers-instead-of-column-names), but the solution has its own problems since we're listing all the column indices instead of the column names. I have way too many columns for me to list them all for each calculation.

Any solutions?

**EDIT:** I figured one out myself, but I feel like it's too inelegant and I believe I'm maybe extracting the entire column for every row, which is obviously going to be a slower solution than expected:

```
data %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(avg = mean(c(.[id, 2:4], recursive=TRUE)))
```

Any solutions that are faster?

Comment: Why not `rowMeans(data[-1])` ?

Comment: @RonakShah you just beat me to it. If its a simple average across all columns but `id`, then his solution can be used as-is. Else you can pass vector of column numbers.

Comment: @chinsoon12 I guess, sure, that'd be nice for general knowledge, but I would prefer a way of doing it that's within the tidyverse.

I could, of course, compute the answer using just rowmeans loops, for example. My larger question is not so much about getting the row means themselves — that's just the particular example that led me to this larger question — but rather about an efficient way of indexing columns with the rowwise() function in tidyverse.

Comment: I don't know that I would use "efficient" when dealing with `rowwise` on data; it works, sure, but while some calculations certainly require it, in general you are defeating R's efficiency calculating on whole vectors at a time. I understand that you are using `rowMeans` as a method for understanding how to deal with data in this fashion, but ... perhaps your *real* problem might also not need `rowwise`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
df %>%
 mutate(c = rowMeans(select(., 2:3)))

   id a b   c
1 101 1 2 1.5
2 102 2 2 2.0
3 103 3 2 2.5
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 mutate(c = rowMeans(select(., 2:length(.))))
```

Answer (score 1):

For me using `rowMeans` seems straightforward without involving `tidyverse` functions.

```
data$c <- rowMeans(data[2:3])
```

however, if you prefer `tidyverse` solution we can take a bit of help from `purrr` `map` functions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
```

For only two columns

```
data %>% mutate(c = map2_dbl(a, b, ~mean(c(.x, .y))))
```

For many columns

```
data %>%  mutate(c = pmap_dbl(select(., a:b), ~mean(c(...))))
```